# CSS properties won't go away

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, stylesheet, assets

Having problems with Rails 3.2.3

I have 3 CSS files in /assets/stylesheets:

- application.css (has require_self & require_tree .)
- bootstrap.css
- myapp.css

Running rails server on localhost:3000, all is well

Whenever I change a CSS property, it gets updated in the view (e.g. change a color).  However, whenever I delete a CSS property, nothing happens.  In fact, I can remove all the text from all the CSS files and nothing will change.

I've tried resetting everything: rails server, clear browser everything, restart all programs, to no avail.

Anyone know what is wrong?

Edit: this problem started after I ran

```
rake assets:precompile
```

and the "fallback" CSS style when I delete properties from the static CSS files (i.e. what it will default to) is based on whatever the CSS files looked like last time I ran rake assets:precompile

Comment: I have config.cache_classes set to false in environments/development.rb.  Are there any other settings that make sense to change?

Comment: Gabe might mean that your browser is caching the stylesheet. Have you inspected the element (using your browser developer tools) that's retaining the css property? That will probably give away how the styles are being applied.

Comment: Thanks Adam.  It is coming from application.css, and when I <link href="..."> to the CSS files manually, there is no problem.  Is there a setting that recompiles the application.css with every page refresh?

Comment: @tyler have you compiled ur assets? Using rake assets:precompile?

Comment: @shreedhar see my edit above; none of this was a problem until I ran rake assets:precompile for the first time.  Is there a cached file somewhere that I can delete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Rake assets:clean
```

will work for you, as u ll be having compiled css and javascript files in your public folder, so by removing those your problem will be solved.

Comment: Excellent, using Rake assets:clean fixed the problem, after also restarting the server and clearing browser cache

Comment: You need to precompile your assets at the time of putting ur app on production.

Comment: Yes, looks like I will have to do rake assets:precompile, then deploy to heroku, then do rake assets:clean each time.  Would be nice if there was a way to do it separately for production only...